# ARRAY BANCO DE DADOS

Tags: php, mysql, array

Pessoal  criei um formulário onde vou colocar a quantidade dos produtos e enviar para o banco dados, só que quando eu clico em enviar não está salvado  só salva de um em um, alguém poderia me ajuda estou tentando criar isso a dias e não estou conseguindo.

aqui esta a tabela criada,
oque eu preciso e enviar todos de uma vez só. alguem poderia me ajuda?
esse codigo em baixo está funcianado perfeitamente so que envia de 1 em 1 preciso que envie todos de uma vez só.

```
 <tr>
             <td><input type="text" readonly class="form-control" name="codigo[]" id="inlineFormInputGroup" value="091822"></td>
             <td><input type="text" readonly class="form-control" name="material[]" id="inlineFormInputGroup" value="TOMATE GRAPE 180"></td>
             <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantidade[]" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Valor" ></td>
      
 </tr>
 <tr>
             <td><input type="text" readonly class="form-control" name="codigo[]" id="inlineFormInputGroup" value="091822"></td>
             <td><input type="text" readonly class="form-control" name="material[]" id="inlineFormInputGroup" value="TOMATE GRAPE 180"></td>
             <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantidade[]" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Valor" ></td>
      
 </tr>[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]
```

```
<?php include_once"conexão.php";?>
<html>
<body>
<?php 

$material = $_POST["material"];
$codigo = $_POST["codigo"];
$quantidade= $_POST["quantidade"];

$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor,$dbusuario,$dbsenha,$dbname);
mysqli_select_db($conn,'$dbname');
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblavitaperdas (material,codigo,quantidade) VALUES ('$material','$codigo','$quantidade')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "<script>alert('Salvei seus dados !'); window.location = 'perdaslavita.php';</script>";

}else{
 echo "Deu errro: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Boa noite, faz tempo que não mexo com php, mas quando você dá o post dos dados, você precisa percorrer eles com um foreach e então inserir no banco de dados, e nesse seu caso, você está inserindo uma única vez pelo que posso ver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu input de CODIGO,MATERIAL e QUANTIDADE você pode receber múltiplos valores, então você receberá um `ARRAY` no PHP.

Exemplo de utilização, utilizando o seu caso:

```
$material = $_POST["material"];
$codigo = $_POST["codigo"];
$quantidade= $_POST["quantidade"];
$total_codigo = count($codigo);

$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor,$dbusuario,$dbsenha,$dbname);
mysqli_select_db($conn,'$dbname');

for($i = 0; $i < $total_codigo; $i++){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO tblavitaperdas (material,codigo,quantidade) VALUES 
           ('$material[$i]','$codigo[$i]','$quantidade[$i]')";
   
   mysqli_query($conn, $sql)

}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: muito obg cara deu certo!

Comment: Boa, se puder marcar como resposta correta eu agradeço.

Comment: Felipe cara por gentileza poderia me ajuda mais em uma coisa cara ? esse alteração que vc fez está perfeita, só não estou conseguindo enviar do jeito certo ainda, acabei de abrir uma nova enquete lá no feed de pergutas poderia me ajuda la de novo?

Comment: na minha tabela tem vários campos inputs só que sou estou querendo pega os que eu quero marcada quantidade for maior que 0, no meu banco registra todos, resumido so queria registra oq eu marca a quantidade relevante maior que 0, eu estava querendo ti marca nos cometarios mais não conseguir vc me ajudou muito valeu!!